# Cannot catch value from form_hidden on codeigniter?

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, post

I try to create Update Form with form helper CI. everything Work if  on form_input. But, when id on form_hidden, it return NULL. this the script
**on View**

```
$hidden = array('name'=>'id_hidden','value'=>$datacompany[0]->id);
echo form_hidden($hidden); //I have edited
```

**On Controller**

```
function edit_company()
{
    if(isset($_POST['EDIT']))
    {
        print_r($_POST);//return All value

        $isi = array(
                 'id'   =>$this->input->post('id_hidden'),//return null
                 'nip'  =>$this->input->post('nip'),//return value
                 'nama' =>$this->input->post('nama'), //return value
             'golongan' =>$this->input->post('golongan') //return value

                );

            echo $isi['id']; //the result id is null
    }//end if
}//end Function
```

That Id I need for using on model. How Can I Fix That?
How to Catch ID from form_hidden?

I'm very appreciated Your Answer

thanks

Comment: Does it actually get printed on the html? 
Do you see a well structured hidden input field with a value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While using my first comment will let you debug it in 3 seconds, Here's the answer :)

You're using the form_hidden in the wrong way.

An array in the form_hidden turns to this (from the docs)

```
$data = array(
          'name'  => 'John Doe',
          'email' => 'john@example.com',
          'url'   => 'http://example.com'
        );
```

echo form_hidden($data);

// Would produce:

```
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="John Doe" />
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="john@example.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="http://example.com" />
```

As you see, the 'keys' of the array turn to the names of the fields. 
The value is the 'value' of the array. so in your example, you're making **two** hidden fields.

```
 <input type="hidden" name="name" value="id_hidden">
<input type="hidden" name="value" value="$datacompany[0]->id">
```

Comment: Hi @Patrick I have Edited my Question. on my view file, the script is $hidden = array('name'=>'id_hidden','value'=>$datacompany[0]->id);
echo form_hidden($hidden); and the value cant pass to the file controller.

Comment: I answered your question in the body of this answer,

The array is formed wrong and it creates two input fields with two names, one for each 'key' in the array.

Comment: Hey, it work. Thanks A Lot. I dont know the form hidden is different with form input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define like this a hidden field in CI:

```
$hidden = array('id_hidden',$datacompany[0]->id); // a name and value pair for a single instance.
echo form_hidden($hidden);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$hidden = array('id_hidden' =>  $datacompany[0]->id);
echo form_hidden($hidden);
```

I think this will fulfill your need.
Or if you want other attributes... Try with this..

```
$data = array(
              'name'        => 'username',
              'id'          => 'username',
              'value'       => 'johndoe',
              'maxlength'   => '100',
              'type'        => 'hidden',
              'size'        => '50',
              'style'       => 'width:50%',
            );

echo form_input($data);
```

Depend on your need.